# how to remove data from chiptagBody in javascript

Tags: javascript, jstl

I am not able delete the data from ChipTagBody.removeAuditPeriod() is getting called properly but data still showing in UI.

```
 <c:set var="idRow" value="${auditPeriod.auditPeriodId}" />
  <span id=Period'+idRow+' class="ChipTagBody"><span class="ChipTagContent"><a onclick="removeAuditPeriod(idRow)" class="ChipTagClose" role="presentation">×</a><c:out value="${auditPeriod.auditPeriodFrom} - ${auditPeriod.auditPeriodTo}"></c:out></span></span>

function removeAuditPeriod(idRow) {
        auditPeriodId = null;
        $('#' + 'Period' + idRow).remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ID Attribute seems to be malformed.

`<span id=Period'+idRow+'>` doesn't look right.

It should probably be something like `<span id="Period${idRow}">` right?